# How to ignore highlight in a channel in irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

Say I have the highlight `c++` in irssi to get alerts for it, but I don't want to receive alerts when `c++` is mentioned in the `#c++` channel. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Set another hilight that sets the color to %n (default) before the main hilight, e.g.:

```
/hilight -channel #c++ -line -color %n c++
/hilight -line -color %R c++
```